# Multiple entries with scaffolding

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

I am using asp.net web forms with c# and use scaffolding to create the views for adding entries to my database.

Now to my question: Is there a way to add multiply entries (through scaffolding)?

For example: I want it to be possible to add another entry field for a phone number (or something else) if the user has already filled in one in the first line.

Is this possible by using scaffolding or other extensions (if yes, how do I get it going?)? Do i have to modify the views/templates by myself? Are there any known projects where this is already realised?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the scaffolding feature, you have to add a new field for example Phone1 and Phone2 and then read them on the post action as you need and may be concatenate them, else you will need to edit the template your self.